# Which is the Java Type for a PHP Project in PDT Eclipse PHP Development Tools

Tags: php, eclipse, project

Does PHP Project also inherits from org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**All** Eclipse projects of any type have an `IProject`.

The different types of project may also have their own project type with additional information. For example a Java project has `IJavaProject`. I don't know what PDT uses.

Comment: Thank you @greg-449